# Feature function in the map.on method

Tags: openlayers

I'm getting the data, but the formatting is not correct. I'm selecting points, at the same point there may be more than one data. With the foreach the information goes out of the mode:

```
0102JohnBryan2019-03-122019-04-26image_car1.jpgimage_car2.jpg
```

It should have a format like this at the same point:

```
01 John 2019-03-12 image_car1.jpg

02 Bryan 2019-04-26 image_car2.jpg
```

I tried to put a for loop, but I'm very afraid that I mustn't have applied it well because it hasn't worked for me.

This is the code with the foreach loop:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
    //var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel);
    var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layers) {
        return feature;
    });
    if (feature.length > 0) {
        var one = document.getElementById('code');
        one.innerHTML = '';
        var two = document.getElementById('autorOb');
        two.innerHTML = '';
        var three = document.getElementById('dateOb');
        three.innerHTML = '';
        var four = document.getElementById('ImgOb');
        four.innerHTML = '';
        feature.forEach(function(feature){
            one.innerHTML += feature.get('id_code');
            two.innerHTML += feature.get('autor');
            three.innerHTML += feature.get('obs_date');
            four.innerHTML += feature.get('image');
        })
    }
});
```

I tried:

```
for (i=0; i<feature.length; i++){
    one.innerHTML += feature.get('id_code');
    two.innerHTML += feature.get('autor');
    three.innerHTML += feature.get('obs_date');
    four.innerHTML += feature.get('image');
}
```

But `feature` is not a function

How can I do it?

Comment: In your `for` loop you forgot the index, it should be `feature[i].get('id_code')`.

Comment: It's true, a mistake when typing the code. I was having problems with the lenght property,and I wrote several versions of the script. wrong version... oh ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to conceptualize your goal.

1. Row based: you can write an entire record info, then a second one etc.

To achieve this, you wouldn't write in each `one` `two` `three` `four` sections (div ?), but rather in a new one (which could have sub-sections of the 4 specific type)

```js
var records = document.getElementById('records');
records.innerHTML = '';

feature.forEach(function(feature){
            records.innerHTML += '<div>';
            records.innerHTML += '  <div class="one">' + feature.get('id_code') + '</div>';
            records.innerHTML += '  <div class="two">' + feature.get('autor') + '</div>';
            records.innerHTML += '  <div class="three">' + feature.get('obs_date') + '</div>';
            records.innerHTML += '  <div class="four">' + feature.get('image') + '</div>';
            records.innerHTML += '</div>';
        })
```

2. Column based: you can write to each of the sections as you are doing, but you need to separate each "row", at the bare minimum with a line break (though you will likely want a fancier div with its own class and formating)

```js
feature.forEach(function(feature){
            one.innerHTML += feature.get('id_code') + '<BR />';
            two.innerHTML += feature.get('autor') + '<BR />';
            three.innerHTML += feature.get('obs_date') + '<BR />';
            four.innerHTML += feature.get('image') + '<BR />';
        })
```

Comment: Perfect! The first solution works perfectly for me, I save code. Now I have just to page the results. Thaks